# Batch file to delete Chrome / Opera old install version folders

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, version

Opera and Chrome create folders for new versions. For example, under %ProgramW6432%\Opera are: 
57.0.3098.63_0 
58.0.3135.21 
58.0.3135.26 
58.0.3135.30 
58.0.3135.37 
58.0.3135.45 
58.0.3135.59 
Assets 
old_status 

I would like to write a batch file that delete all older Opera versions folders created on install new version process, except the latest two newest folders. In this case: 58.0.3135.45 and 58.0.3135.59 folders.
Note: For Chrome is similar, but in addition is to rename "new_chrome.exe" file to "chrome.exe".

I wrote below code to find the oldest and newest folder but I'm stuck.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

REM %ProgramW6432%\Net\Opera
REM D:\Program Files\Net\Opera
SET path=%ProgramW6432%\Net\Opera

ECHO. & ECHO. %path% & ECHO.

FOR /F " tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /B /AD-H /OGD "%path%\5*"') DO (SET fistDIR=%%i)
ECHO. & ECHO. The newest install folder created under %path% is %fistDIR% & 
ECHO.

FOR /F " tokens=*" %%j IN ('DIR /B /AD-H /OG-D "%path%\5*"') DO (SET lastDIR=%%j)
ECHO. & ECHO. The oldest install folder created under %path% is %lastDIR% & 
ECHO.
```

Comment: I am a bit confused with what you actually want..

Comment: For new Chrome / Opera version is created a new folder with version number as name (for example: 58.0.3135.30). These folders are never deleted. My intention is to create a batch script which will delete automatically these folders

Comment: So the uninstall of the older version retains the folders?

Comment: No to uninstall. Only to delete them. Only the last created folder is latest Chrome version. I want to keep the latest two because, maybe, the latest version can be damaged.

Comment: but you realise that if you do not uninstall them properly, you will have shared files, registry keys etc that are not removed with the removal if the directories, right?

Comment: but, if you are really looking at doing it, then maybe sort by latest folder? `for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%i in ('dir "%mypath%\5*" /b /O-D') do echo rmdir /S "%%~i"` This will just echo the rmdir command so you can see if the results will be ok, without actually deleting them.

Comment: Actually I don't want to uninstall the Chrome. My intention is to delete all older folders created on install new versions process. That's why I want to keep the latest two folders.

Comment: ok, so did you try my suggestion in my last comment?

Comment: Do not use `%path%` as a generic name. It's an important system environment variable.

Comment: and as @montonero just highligted, you need to change any `%path%` variable to `%mypath%`becaus you are breaking your environment.

Comment: Now I'm in office but I will try it at home. Your last comment is very useful and I understand why other command are not running after I used %path%. Thanks for tip!

Comment: Please include all relevant information in your question by [edit]ing it!

Comment: Like i said. You need to remove `echo` from the script before `rmdir` It only `echo`s the command as a safe measure. Remove it to actually perform the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to complete the script, excluding the echo:

```
set "mypath=Z:\"
cd /d "%mypath%"
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%i IN ('dir "%mypath%5*" /B /AD /O-D') do RMDIR /S /Q "%%~fi"
```